# RTS like Mouse in an isometric view (LWJGL)

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl, isometric

I really have an issue with mouseclicks in an isometric view. 
Simply i have a flat map, and, like i said, a camera in an isometric view. Now when i click in the window i want to get the Coordinates where i clicked on the map. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, i figured it out.

```
int winX = ...  //the x coordinate of the Click, given Parameter
int winY = ... //the y Coordinate of the Click, given Parameter
FloatBuffer winZ = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(1); //the x coordinate of the click, will be calculated
FloatBuffer pos = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3); // the final position of the click
FloatBuffer modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16); 
FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16); 
IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16); 

GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTIONMATRIX, projection);

GL11.glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1,1, GL11._GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL11.GL_FLOAT, winZ) //calculate the Z Coordinate of the Click
GLU.gluUnProject((float)(winX), (float)(winY), (float)(winZ.get(0)), modelview, projection, viewport, pos); //Calculating the 3D Position of the click, saved in pos
```

Now since you have the 3D Coordinates you can do some simple vector calculation and collision detection to get the point you clicked on

Comment: You don't need to use glReadPixels, just assume the Z component is 0.5 or so (i.e. half-way between the near and far clip plane) and you'll get the same result.